# If $a+bc$ and $c$ have irreducible factors in common, then $a$ and $c$ have the same irreducible factors in common.

Tags: prime-factorization, principal-ideal-domains

Let $a,b,c \in K[t]$ where $K$ is field with characteristic not $2$ or $3$ and see title for the question. This is a problem I encountered in showing the image of some map is finite, which I need in my thesis. I tried decomposing in irreducible elements, but I got stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean that "$a + bc$ have irreducible factors in common"? That's a single element of $K[t]$.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have edited the question.

Comment: If $a+bc=pq, c=pr$ for some irreducible $p$, then $a=p(q-br)$ so I think it's done.

Comment: I don’t understand the question. Do you mean that $a$ and $c$ have the same irreducible factors as each other, or that any common factor of $a + bc$ and $c$ is also a factor of $a$? In either case (respectively), egreg and nessy’s answers seem legit.

Comment: It's saying that all the common factors of $a+bc$ and $c$ are also common factors of $a$ and $c$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $a=6$, and $c=2$. Then $a+bc$ and $c$ have the factor $2$ in common, but $a$ has the factor $3$ that's not common to $c$.

These are integers, you'd object. But it's the same over any UFD with at least two distinct irreducible elements $p$ and $q$. Take $a=pq$ and $c=p$.

The ring $K[t]$ has *infinitely* many irreducible elements, so you're doomed.

Comment: I think I might have phrased the question wrong. In your case we would have: $6+2b$ and $2$ having the factor $2$ in common. However, $a$ and $c$ also have this factor 2 in common. $a$ and $c$ don't need to have the same factors. They only need to have the same factors that $a+bc$ and $c$ have in common.

Comment: @Math4Life Then the problem is trivial, isn't it? If $d$ is a common factor of $a+bc$ and of $c$, then $d$ is a factor of $a=(a+bc)-bc$.